# Linux computer booting into wrong partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I restarted my desktop computer with Ubuntu 14.04. Afterwards, it logged into an old partition that I didn't even know existed with the previous user's Ubuntu installation. I thought that installation had been removed with the reinstallation of Ubuntu, but apparently not.

When in that wrong partition, it's reporting a bunch of I/O errors such as `Buffer I/O error on sda2, logical block 1, lost async page write` and `blk_update_request: I/O error ,dev sea, section 1050632`. I'm not looking into those as I hope they go away when I load into the correct partition.

How do I ensure that the machine logs into the right partition with my user?

**Edit:** I've added the requested information below. I wasn't sure how best to extract it from the computer so I took pictures. Let me know if there's anything I need to add or clarify!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide more info and post: a list of **your partitions** with parted/fdisk the config of your bootloader **grub.cfg** in /boot/grub/ and for the block errors your mount list in /etc/**fstab** to make us look into it and scan for obvious errors.

Comment: @HansPropotkin Do you see any obvious errors? Is there anything I could do to make it easier for you?